# Could java.util.ArrayList<T>.toArray() be made friendlier?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I'm surprised by how painful it is to use java.util.ArrayList<T>.toArray().

Suppose I declare my array list as:

```
java.util.ArrayList<double[]> arrayList = new java.util.ArrayList<double[]>();
... add some items ...
```

Then to convert it to an array, I have to do one of the following:

```
double[][] array = (double[][])arrayList.toArray(new double[0][]);
```

or:

```
double[][] array = (double[][])arrayList.toArray(new double[arrayList.size()][]);
```

or:

```
double[][] array = new double[arrayList.size()];
arrayList.toArray(array);
```

None of the above are very readable.  Shouldn't I be able to say the following instead?

```
double[][] array = arrayList.toArray();
```

But that gives a compile error because Object[] can't be converted to double[][].

Perhaps it's not possible because toArray has to return Object[]
for backwards compatibility with pre-template days.
But if that's the case, couldn't a friendlier alternative method be added
with a different name?  I can't think of a good name, but almost anything
would be better than the existing ways; e.g. the following would be fine:

```
double[][] array = arrayList.toArrayOfNaturalType();
```

No such member function exists, but maybe it's possible to write a generic helper function that will do it?

```
double[][] array = MyToArray(arrayList);
```

The signature of MyToArray would be something like:

```
public static <T> T[] MyToArray(java.util.ArrayList<T> arrayList)
```

Is it possible to implement such a function?
My various attempts at implementing it resulted in compile errors
"error: generic array creation" or "error: cannot select from a type variable".

Here's the closest I was able to get:

```
public static <T> T[] MyToArray(java.util.ArrayList<T> arrayList, Class type)
{
    T[] array = (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(type, arrayList.size());
    arrayList.toArray(array);
    return array;
}
```

It's called like this:

```
double[][] array = MyToArray(arrayList, double[].class);
```

I wish the redundant final parameter wasn't there, but, even so,
I think this is the least-horrible way that I've seen so far for converting array list to array.

Is it possible to do any better than this?

Comment: The fundamental problem is that the type T isn't known at runtime due to erasure, so you can't create a T[] without some help.

Comment: Is there some reason you absolutely need a type like `List<double[]>`? Generics and arrays just don't mix.

Comment: @dimo414 What I want in the end is a double[][2];  I'm using an ArrayList to build it incrementally since I don't know what the final size will be beforehand.  Is ArrayList not the right tool for this?

Comment: Use a `List<List<Double>>`. If you *must* you can copy the final result to an array, but that's rarely necessary. Just stick with the collection types throughout your application and you'll be much happier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot write

```
double[][] array = arrayList.toArray();
```

The reason is that `toArray()` was defined in JDK 1.2 (prior to generics) to return `Object[]`. This cannot be changed compatibly.

Generics were introduced in Java 5 but were implemented using erasure. This means that the `ArrayList` instance has no knowledge at runtime of the types of objects it contains; therefore, it cannot create an array of the desired element type. That's why you have to pass a type token of some sort -- in this case an actual array instance -- to tell `ArrayList` the type of the array to create.

You should be able to write

```
double[][] array = arrayList.toArray(new double[0][]);
```

without a cast. The one-arg overload of `toArray()` is generified, so you'll get the right return type.

One might think that it's preferable to pass a pre-sized array instead of a throwaway zero-length array. Aleksey Shipilev wrote an [article](http://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/) analyzing this question. The answer is, somewhat counterintuitively, that creating a zero-length array is potentially faster.

Briefly, the reason is that allocation is cheap, a zero-length array is small, and it's probably going to be thrown away and garbage collected quickly, which is also cheap. By contrast, creating a pre-sized array requires it to be allocated and then filled with nulls/zeroes. It's then passed to `toArray()`, which then fills it with values from the list. Thus, every array element is typically written twice. By passing a zero-length array to `toArray()`, this allows the array allocation to occur in the same code as the array filling code, providing the opportunity for the JIT compiler to bypass the initial zero-fill, since it knows that every array element will be filled.

There is also [JDK-8060192](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8060192) which proposes to add the following:

```
<A> A[] Collection.toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)
```

This lets you pass a lambda expression that is given the array size and returns a created array of that size. (This is similar to `Stream.toArray()`.) For example,

```
// NOT YET IMPLEMENTED
double[][] array = arrayList.toArray(n -> new double[n][]);
double[][] array = arrayList.toArray(double[][]::new);
```

This isn't implemented yet, but I'm still hopeful this can get into JDK 9.

You could rewrite your helper function along these lines:

```
static <T> T[] myToArray(List<T> list, IntFunction<T[]> generator) {
    return list.toArray(generator.apply(list.size()));
}
```

(Note that there is some subtlety here with concurrent modification of the list, which I'm ignoring for this example.) This would let you write:

```
double[][] array = myToArray(arrayList, double[][]::new);
```

which isn't terribly bad. But it's not actually clear that it's any better than just allocating a zero-length array to pass to `toArray()`.

Finally, one might ask why `toArray()` takes an actual array instance instead of a `Class` object to denote the desired element type. Joshua Bloch (creator of the Java collections framework) said in comments on [JDK-5072831](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-5072831) that this is feasible but that he's not sure it's a good idea, though he could live with it.

There an additional use case here as well, of copying the elements into an existing array, like the old [`Vector.copyInto()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#copyInto-java.lang.Object:A-) method. The array-bearing `toArray(T[])` method also supports this use case. In fact, it's better than `Vector.copyInto()` because the latter cannot be used safely in the presence of concurrent modification, if the collection's size changes. The auto-sizing behavior of `toArray(T[])` handles this, and it also handles the case of creating an array of the caller's desired type as described above. Thus, while adding an overload that takes a `Class` object would certainly work, it doesn't add much over the existing API.

Comment: Oh!  Thank you for the link and synopsis of why the zero-length allocation is faster than the other-- I saw that fact mentioned at  http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/04/11/3-good-reasons-to-avoid-arrays-in-java-interfaces/ and was mystified by it.  This is all really great information.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's awesome and it filled in gaps in my knowledge.  However I think to form a complete picture, there needs to be mention of type erasure as in @StephenC's answer, to explain why the most straightforward API isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks! Updated with more history and rationale.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to do any better than this?

Nope.

> None of the above are very readable. Shouldn't I be able to say the following instead?
>
> ```
> double[][] array = arrayList.toArray();
> ```

It would be nice ... but you can't.

The problem is that the `toArray()` method was specified way back in Java 1.2 with the behavior you are seeing.  Generic types were not added to the language until Java 1.5.  When they were added, the designers chose the "type erasure" approach, for compatibility with earlier versions of Java.  So:

- the semantics of the `toArray()` methods could not be changed without breaking compatibility, and
- type erasure makes it impossible for a `toArray()` method implementation to know what the list's actual element type is, so it could not get it right anyway.

Comment: +1 for providing some history here. I've incorporated some of this material into my answer per request from OP.